# Change top position of a div with scrolling

Tags: jquery, positioning, parallax

I need to know how I can add pixel to the top of a div while I'm scrolling down and remove pixel to the top of a div while I'm scrolling up.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="pourvoirie" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <div id="para">
        <div class="contenantNoir">
            <div class="texte wrap">
                <h1>La pourvoirie</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis mi vel sem sagittis aliquam eu non odio. Aenean nibh sem, aliquam consequat odio at, ultrices luctus felis. Donec eu accumsan nisi. Duis id mi magna. Vestibulum eleifend cursus lacus. Phasellus id erat sollicitudin, mollis urna sed, vestibulum nibh. Vivamus ligula nisi, porttitor eu est vel, imperdiet sollicitudin odio. Morbi a lacus sodales, tristique nunc vel, aliquam dolor. Quisque non venenatis tellus, sed porttitor nisi. Praesent ac commodo purus. Quisque elementum ultrices lectus vel pellentesque. </p>
                <p>Phasellus id erat sollicitudin, mollis urna sed, vestibulum nibh. Vivamus ligula nisi, porttitor eu est vel, imperdiet sollicitudin odio. Morbi a lacus sodales, tristique nunc vel, aliquam dolor. Quisque non venenatis tellus, sed porttitor nisi. Praesent ac commodo Quisque elementum ultrices lectus vel pellentesque. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the script.js

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var positionTopP = $('#pourvoirie').offset().top;
        var positionYP = positionTopP - $(window).scrollTop();
        var positionTopCN = $('.contenantNoir').offset().top;
        var positionYCN = positionTopCN - $(window).scrollTop();
        if(positionYP<=72){
            $('#para').css({ 'top': '0px' });
            $('#para').css({ 'position': 'fixed' });
            $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'padding-top': '+=5' });
            $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'color': 'transparent' });
            $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'text-shadow': '0px 0px 5px #fff' });


                console.log(positionYP);
                if(positionYP<=-350){
                    $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'top': positionYCN });
                    console.log('position:carre noir' + positionYCN);
                }else{
                    /*if(positionYCN==0){
                        $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'top': '0px' });
                    }else{
                        $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'padding-top': '-=5' });
                    }*/
                    $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'padding-top': '-=5' });
                    console.log('ca marche tu?');
                }
            /*if(positionYCN>=179){
                console.log('descend');
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'top': '+=5' });
                    }
                });
            }*/


        }else{
            $('#para').css({ 'top': '46px' });
            $('#para').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
            /*$('#galerie').css({ 'position': 'relative' });*/


        }
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is when `#pourvoirie` is at 72px from the top, I fix the position of the `div`. Next, if I continue to scroll down, `.contenantNoir` will go down but `#pourvoirie` still stay position fixed. If I scroll Up, it will do the same action reversely, which is `.contenantNoir` will go up till it reach a top 0px and after `#pourvoirie` will have a position relative.

Answer (score -1):

here's the solution i found

```
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
        console.log('Down');
           // downscroll code
           if($('.contenantNoir').hasClass('fixed')){
             $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'top': '+=5' });
           }
       } else {
          // upscroll code
          console.log('up');
          if($('.contenantNoir').hasClass('fixed')){
            $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'top': '-=5' });
          }
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
```